# Getting C to wok with assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system

Im working on a simple OS, for the past 3 weeks ive been debugging an error that only arrises when i call c++ or c code in assembly, qemu (the emulator im using), will start flickering and wont load code. I have already tried this with other emulators.

"Bootloader.asm"

```
    [org 0x7c00]
    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x10
    mov [Boot_Disk], dl
    
    mov bp, 0x7c00
    mov sp, bp
    
    call DiskRead
    
    jmp Program_Space
    
    jmp $
    
    %include "ReadDisk.asm"
    
    
    times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ;fills the rest of the bytes till byte 510 with 0s
    db 0x55 ;sets the last 2 bytes to 0x55 and 0xaa, so the bios knows its bootable
    db 0xaa
```

"Sector2.asm"

```
jmp Enable32BitMode
%include "gdt.asm"
Enable32BitMode:

    call enable_A20

    cli ;disables interupts

    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    mov eax, cr0 
    or eax, 1       ; set PE (Protection Enable) bit in CR0 (Control Register 0)
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp codeseg:Start32Bit



enable_A20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    ret       



[bits 32]
;[extern _start]
Start32Bit:

    mov ax, dataseg ;moves dataseg (found in gdt, into registers ds to gs)
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    ;mov [0xb8000], byte 'h'
  ;  call _start
    jmp $

times 2048 - ($-$$) db 0 ;fills the disk with 2kb of 0's
```

"ReadDisk.asm"

```
    Program_Space equ 0x7e00
    
    DiskRead:
        mov ah, 0x02 
        mov bx, Program_Space 
        mov al, 4 ;amount of sectors to read
        mov dl, [Boot_Disk] 
        mov ch, 0x00 ; 
        mov dh, 0x00 ; 
        mov cl, 0x02 ;
    
        int 0x13
```

---

"ReadText.cpp"

```cpp
    extern "C" void _start() {
        return;
    }
```

My compiler options (linux):

```
    nasm Bootloader.asm -f bin -o Bootloader.bin 
    nasm Sector2.asm -f elf32 -o Sector2.o
    gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -mno-red-zone -march=i686 -c "Kernel.c" -o "ReadText.o" # -m32

    ld -m elf_i386 -o Kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x7e00 Sector2.o ReadText.o
    objcopy -O binary Kernel.tmp Kernel.bin 
    cat Bootloader.bin Kernel.bin > Bootloader.flp
```

Dissasembly of c code:

```
Disassembly of section .text:



00000000 <_start>:

  0:   f3 0f 1e fb             endbr32 

  4:   55                      push   %ebp

  5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp

  7:   90                      nop

  8:   5d                      pop    %ebp

  9:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Use the [edit] link and fix the formatting using the code button. Your `DiskRead` does not seem to return. You do not seem to set up segment registers. You seem to be attempting to run 32 bit code in 16 bit mode (might work for your empty function). Apparently even your `Sector2` is assembled as 32 bit ... now that definitely won't work.

Comment: I forgot to add one of my files :D

Comment: You need a stack to be able to `call` anything, especially C code. Shouldn't you set `esp` after switching into protected mode?

Comment: Additionally, I believe `-f elf32` automatically selects `[bits 32]` so you should put a `[bits 16]` at the top of your file to assemble the 16 bit part correctly. Make sure the C code does not have stuff like stack protection canary (verify disassembly).

Comment: Btw, emulators have debuggers (one of the major benefits of using them), so you should be able to single-step your boot code and see where it breaks.  Bochs has a nicer debugger than qemu in this regard.

Comment: When i make a method in Sector2.asm that's 32 bit it works fine, but when the method is 16 bit, the same flickering that happens when my c code is ran happens, doesn't -m32 compile c to 32 bit?

Comment: It does. Look at the disassembly of the generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, i was not reading the sector that held the C code, if you are reading this with this problem, make sure you are reading all of your sectors.

Answer (score 1):

like @jester commented your question. You seem to compile your bootloader as .code32. Your CPU(qemu or any other VM) won't boot it, cause CPU originally runs in 16bit mode. Please take a look here - [JOS bootloader](https://github.com/jkmiva/JOS/blob/master/boot/boot.S) . This is minimalistic bootloader you might learn from.

Comment: Adding [bits 16] to the top didnt work, is this what you meant?

Comment: @Kalix I think saidm referred to the sector2 file.  The top of the file must run in 16 bit mode.

Comment: @Kalix Could you please share your dissassembled C file?   (its better to keep it just C for simplicity for now). Also try to compile your C code with "fno-pie" flag.

Comment: @saidm I tried and it didnt change anything, i added the dissasembly to the question.

Comment: @Kalix , excuse me, I don't see where do you setup your stack (sp/esp reg). Usually you better to put 0x7b00 in your stack pointer register (it grows down). Also, its safer to disable Intel CET (however CPU has to ignore these instructions)  with `-fcf-protection=none`

Comment: @saidm i added the memory address 0x20008000 into esp and im still getting the same problem, is this not how you define the stack pointer?

Comment: Usually you would like to setup your esp closer to your data region or anywhere below first 2-4MB of phys memory, because as soon as you setup your page tables, it would be easier, since it will be enough to setup only one entry in the page table.

Comment: @Kalix   So, about your problem - I would suggest to start your qemu with gdb and step into the instruction which fails exactly. You will see the instruction which fails. ( You also can see that debug log of qemu, should be a triple fault with full regs content. Lookup which address RIP had, then you can use something like addr2line or manually lookup the assembly code to understand which instruction causes the fault.